# MSI GS65 | RTX 2060 | no external monitor | Ubuntu18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I run Ubunutu 18.04 on a MSI GS65. all things are running perfect on the MSI.I faced from provlems installing the graphics card but ended up installing "nvidia-driver-440" which was running great and hdmi sometimes hang and i turn off the screen and turn it on and shut down the laptop then it works.

but now once I switched nvidia-prime to intel hd , then back to RTX2060 , then my HDMI is not not connecting anymore eventhough i tried all the tricks.

here is the outputs of logs that might help:

## inxi -SMCGx

```
System:    Host: m Kernel: 5.3.0-40-generic x86_64 bits: 64 gcc: 7.4.0
           Desktop: Gnome 3.28.4 (Gtk 3.22.30-1ubuntu4)
           Distro: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Micro-Star product: GS65 Stealth 9SE v: REV:1.0 serial: N/A
           Mobo: Micro-Star model: MS-16Q4 v: REV:1.0 serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: E16Q4IMS.110 date: 04/02/2019
CPU:       6 core Intel Core i7-9750H (-MT-MCP-) 
           arch: Skylake rev.10 cache: 12288 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 31199
           clock speeds: max: 4500 MHz 1: 3659 MHz 2: 3707 MHz 3: 3698 MHz
           4: 3735 MHz 5: 3735 MHz 6: 3729 MHz 7: 3716 MHz 8: 3715 MHz
           9: 3723 MHz 10: 3742 MHz 11: 3738 MHz 12: 3718 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 3e9b bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: NVIDIA Device 1f11 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.5 )
           drivers: modesetting,nvidia (unloaded: fbdev,vesa,nouveau)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@240.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce RTX 2060/PCIe/SSE2
           version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 440.59 Direct Render: Yes
```

## lspci -nnk | egrep -A3 -i "3D|VGA"

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e9b]
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1274]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
--
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1f11] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:1274]
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
--
3d:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1969:e0b1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1462:1274]
    Kernel driver in use: alx
    Kernel modules: alx
```

## ls /lib/modprobe.d

```
aliases.conf                               nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf
blacklist_linux-hwe_5.3.0-28-generic.conf  nvidia-kms.conf
blacklist_linux-hwe_5.3.0-40-generic.conf  systemd.conf
fbdev-blacklist.conf
```

## dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-440:amd64                   440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-440                       440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:amd64                440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:i386                 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-440:amd64                 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-440:i386                  440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-440:amd64                 440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-440:i386                  440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-440:amd64                   440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386                    440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-440:amd64                     440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-440:i386                      440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-440:amd64                   440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386                    440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-440                   440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-dkms-440                            440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-440                          440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-440                   440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-440                   440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.8.2                                            all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            440.44-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-440                           440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440              440.59-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                            amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

## mokutil --sb-state

```
SecureBoot disabled
```

## xrandr --prop

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP-1-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff004d10c51400000000
        091d0104a522137807de50a3544c9926
        0f505400000001010101010101010101
        01010101010150d0805070381f401828
        350058c2100000181434805070381f40
        1828350058c210000018000000100000
        000000000000000000000000000000fc
        004c513135364d314a5730330a2000e4
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    scaling mode: Full aspect 
        supported: Full, Center, Full aspect
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 86 
        supported: 86
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
   1920x1080    240.00*+  60.00  
DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (6, 12)
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 92 
        supported: 92
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    max bpc: 12 
        range: (8, 12)
    content type: No Data 
        supported: No Data, Graphics, Photo, Cinema, Game
    Colorspace: Default 
        supported: Default, SMPTE_170M_YCC, BT709_YCC, XVYCC_601, XVYCC_709, SYCC_601, opYCC_601, opRGB, BT2020_CYCC, BT2020_RGB, BT2020_YCC, DCI-P3_RGB_D65, DCI-P3_RGB_Theater
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 99 
        supported: 99
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
```

Any advice on this matter ?, I have been really suffering for this to be consistent in ubuntu but somehow it doesn't happen , so i would really appreicate if someone can help here.

Cheers
Mo